# Is there any way to reduce pg_largeobject size?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

The Backup team are concerned about DB backup since it's huge and taking a long time to back up (physical backup - 300 GB - approx 5hrs). 90% of data is in *pg_largeobject*.

I could remove *loid* which are not required with a plain delete query or by doing *lo_unlink* and running *vacuum* on it. But I would like to know if there is any way to compress the data to reduce the table size without removing any rows in the *pg_largeobject* table?

(Using PostgreSQL 9.1.)

Update:

As per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636850/does-pg-database-size-include-blobs-in-pg-largeobject , on every insert in *pg_largeobject* will be compressed  (Answer by Craig). Is my understanding is correct? or do I need to enable any settings to achieve the compression?

Comment: Does that all mean that you don't really have to dump the contents of `pg_largeobject`?  And how exactly are you doing the backup?

Comment: If this table has a lot of activity, maybe vacuuming would help, but the cure might be worse than the disease... Or maybe some partionning with old data moved to a different place?

Comment: @dezso, I am using pg_dump and i need to take all data. I heard from one of my friend (Oracle dba), mentioned that in oracle db they could compress the blob data, so the db size will be reduced, and backup timing as well.

Comment: @KookieMonster, by doing partitioning I hope still the loid present in the same table (only the user table data will be moved to partitioned table - data (blob) remains in pg_largeobject only). correct me if i wrong.